# MPI for should be executed non-parallel, but his body ofc yes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi

How can I do something in parallel inside for loop? I mean that loop should be executed in one thread but his body should be executed parallel. But this code hasn't work:

```
int main(){
    int ID;
    int PROCESSES;
    int source;
    int dest;
    int tag = 50;
    char message[100];
    MPI::Status status;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        MPI::Init();

        ID = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

        cout << "some text " << ID << " " << i << endl;

        MPI::Finalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using OpenMP to parallelize the for loop? MPI inherently launches multiple processes (not threads).

Comment: You know, I really need to write solution of problem using MPI

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding about what MPI is. MPI doesn't automatically parallelize code, but gives you the ability to send messages from one process to another. When you execute your application, you say how many "copies" of the program to execute and then within the program, you explicitly tell MPI to send data from one process to another.

There are some very specific problems in your code as well. You can only call MPI_Init and MPI_Finalize once per process and it should be the first and last thing in your code. So your code should look something like this:

```
int main(){
    int ID;
    int PROCESSES;
    int source;
    int dest;
    int tag = 50;
    char message[100];
    MPI::Status status;

    MPI::Init();
    ID = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << "some text " << ID << " " << i << endl;
    }

    MPI::Finalize();
}
```

Obviously, that code doesn't do anything useful, but just prints out each process's rank three times, but it's an example.

I'd recommend finding a good example of using MPI on the web. Your favorite search engine should be your friend here.

Comment: Ok I know but I though it is possible to make something like this via MPI.